# File Not Found Error in Google Colab Python Code for ML , dataset loading

Tags: python, training-data

I have written this code in Colab:

```
# load the dataset
X_train, y_train = load_house_data()
X_features = ['size(sqft)','bedrooms','floors','age']
```

But this is showing File Not  Found Error, repeatedly.

But I have uploaded all the datasets and codes in Colab successfully. Stucked with this problem for 2 days. Tried all possible things I can do, but all in vain. Please help.
For more detail please check these two pics:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Anybody, any help please!